Trouble scrolling (swiping) over link elements on mobile
I have a list of images within  tags that link to project pages  . On mobile they take up most of the screen, and if you try to scroll over the clickable area nothing happens.
Tried this:
var disable_click_flag = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    disable_click_flag = true;

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));

    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        disable_click_flag = false;
    }, 250));
});

$("body").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    if( disable_click_flag ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

From another thread on here, didn't work.
Thank you!

I would try to ensure the click event is fully disabled while scrolling. You can modify the time out (250)
var disableClickFlag = false; $(window).on('scroll', function() { disableClickFlag = true; clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer')); $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() { disableClickFlag = false; }, 250)); }); $("body").on("click", "a", function(e) { if (disableClickFlag) { e.preventDefault(); return false; } });


did you test this? It works on pc, but it seems to me that on mobile the click event precedes the scroll on swiping, preventing the scroll.
